# White line between linear-gradient and box-shadow with vertically centered elements

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When combining a `vertical-gradient` and a `box-shadow` on a vertical centered element it displays a white line between the element and the shadow (at certain sizes).

To be able to show the problem the code snippet forces a size where this problem occurs, in the real case example the heigh scales with the viewport.

This issue happens on Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Safari renders well, didn't test any other browser).

**Is there any workarounds that could solve this issue apart of dropping the gradient?**

```css
.center {
  height: 96px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 61%;
  margin: auto 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  box-shadow: navy 0 20px 0;
}

.box--grad {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top, #207ee2 60%, #90bded 150%);
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box box--grad"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying a `background-position-y: -1px;` rule to the gradient seems to solve the problem, without having a negative effect on other browsers (tested on Firefox).

```css
.center {
  height: 96px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 61%;
  margin: auto 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  box-shadow: navy 0 20px 0;
}

.box--grad {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top, #207ee2 60%, #90bded 150%);
  background-position-y: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box box--grad"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can slightly increase the `background-size`:

```css
.center {
  height: 96px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 61%;
  margin: auto 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  box-shadow: navy 0 20px 0;
}

.box--grad {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top, #207ee2 60%, #90bded 150%);
  background-size:100% calc(100% + 1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box box--grad"></div>
</div>
```

Or adjust the background-position to bottom (in case the shadow is always applied to the bottom)

```css
.center {
  height: 96px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 61%;
  margin: auto 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  box-shadow: navy 0 20px 0;
}

.box--grad {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top, #207ee2 60%, #90bded 150%) bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box box--grad"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide alternative solutions. Truth is that both solution work on the example provided, but some reason I cannot fully understand it does not work on my current application. Adjusting the `background-position-y` works though. I could also make it work with `background-size: 100% calc(100% + 2px)`, and position the background on bottom as no effect. My problem looks, indeed, very sketchy.

Comment: @a--m can you share more code related to you application? we may find more alternatives. Gradient are very tricky and each situation is somehow unique.

Comment: I thought I did put all the relevant code, and it took me a while to reproduce the issue on a code-snippet, but it looks like what I did wasn't enough, so I'll get back to it when I have some time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use a

> :after

```css
.content{
    height: 96px;
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
}
.box {
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
.box-shadow1{
     background: radial-gradient(circle at top, #00448b 60%, #6dfff1 150%);}
 .box-shadow2{
    background: radial-gradient(circle at top, #ffec04 , #f48f11 );}
 .box-shadow1:after {
       width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 47px 0px #29adec;
}
 .box-shadow2:after {
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px #a67300;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="box box-shadow1"></div>
  <div class="box box-shadow2"></div>
</div>
```